# Как при нажатии на кнопку вверх и вниз прокручивать списки

Tags: javascript, меню

Добавил кнопки вверх и вниз.

1. Не знаю как их прикрутить, чтобы при нажатии на эти кнопки происходил скролл вверх и вниз.
2. Как заставить `mousewheel` работать в Mozilla

```js
var log = console.log;

$('.child').hide();
$('.parent').children().click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
});

$(function () {
 var container = $('.container');
    var parent = $('.parent');
    parent.on('mousewheel  DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll  ', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
        var $this = $(this);
        var scrollHeight = ($this.outerHeight() - container.height()) * (-1);
        var course = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        var top = parseInt($this.css('top'));
        
        var children = $this.find('.parent')
        top += course;

        if (course > 0) {
         $("#btn-up").addClass("button-up");
            $("#btn-down").removeClass("button-down");
         
         $this.css({
                'top': (top < 0) ? top : 0
            });
            children.css({
                
                'top': (top < 0) ? -top : 0
            });
      
        } else {
         $("#btn-up").removeClass("button-up");
            $("#btn-down").addClass("button-down");
            
            
            $this.css({
               
                'top': (top > scrollHeight) ? top : scrollHeight
            });
            children.css({
                'top': (top > scrollHeight) ? -top : -scrollHeight
            });
        }
        
    })
});







/*HOVER BLOCK MENU*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container ul li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').show();
    }, function(){
            $(this).find('ul:first').hide();
        });                         
});





$('.par>li').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.parent').css("top", '0');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
 
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent {
    top: 0;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
}

.container ul li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
/*    border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;*/
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

li {
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

.container ul {
    height:auto;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    width: 250px;
  /*  background-color: royalblue;*/
    overflow: visible;
}


.dropdown-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #0f1e41;
}

.submenu-one {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    right: -250px;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #18316a;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover .submenu-one  {
    /*display: block;*/
}

.submenu-one li:hover {
    background-color: #0f1e41;
}

.submenu-two {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #112551;
}

.submenu-one li:hover .submenu-two {
    /*display: block;*/
}

.submenu-two li:hover {
    background-color: #0f1e41;
}

.submenu-three {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #112551;
}

.submenu-two li:hover .submenu-three {
    /*display: block;*/
}

.button-up {
    display: none;
}

.button-down {
    display: none;
}


.button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
   
    
}

.up-block, .down-block {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mega menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
     <div class="up-block"> <button id="btn-up" class="button">Вверх</button></div>
     
    <div class="container">
       
    
        <ul class="parent  dropdown-menu">
            <li class="">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">1-1</a>

                <ul class="parent submenu-one">
                    <li class=""><a href="#">2</a>
                        <ul class="parent submenu-two ">
                            <li><a href="#">3-1</a>
                                <ul class="parent submenu-three">
                                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">3-2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3-3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3-4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">2</a>
                    <ul class="parent submenu-two ">
                        <li><a href="#">3-2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1-3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1-4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="down-block"><button id="btn-down" class="button">Вниз</button></div>
     

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/menu.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавить полифил для поддержки этого метода.
https://gist.github.com/SebLambla/f311fe469a958e3784bb552d9e320954 как вариант.